# SQL - select data that have dates greater than a month in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `quiz` and it has 3 columns:

```
enterYear  enterMonth  quizMark

2013        7            9.5   
2013        8            8.5    
2013        9            9.75    
2013       10            10    
2013       11            7.75    
2013       12            8.5
2014        1            5   
2014        2            8.75    
2014        3            10
```

Now, I want to select the entries that were enter after Sept. of 2013 (including Sept). I tried this which was wrong:

```
select * from quiz q where q.year>=2013 and q.month>=9
```

This omitted all the entries in 2014 since their months are less than 9, but I do want them in the result since they are after Sept. of 2013.

So then, I tried this

```
select * from quiz q 
where Convert(date, CAST(q.year as varchar(4))+'/'+CAST(q.month as varchar(2))+'/01')>='2013/9/01'
```

which showed up the result for like a half second and then quickly disappeared by giving an error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Can someone help with the correct code to achieve the result, very appreciated!

Comment: If it showed the result for a second, then gave you an error, there may be a specific row in your table that cannot be converted (for example, one entry in the year column that is not numeric).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from quiz q where q.year>2013 or(q.year=2013 and q.month>=9)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from quiz q where (q.year>=2013 and q.month>=9) OR q.year>=2014
```

This will capture all your dates from September 2013 upwards.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your indexes you might find this gives better performance. Expressing as a single range seek with a residual predicate rather than `or` which often causes a scan.

```
select * 
from quiz q 
where (q.year>=2013) and (q.month>=9 OR q.year>=2014)
```